# Twig Variable Scope in Loop

Tags: symfony, twig

From the [twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html):

> Note that loops are scoped in Twig; therefore a variable declared
>   inside a for loop is not accessible outside the loop itself. If you
>   want to access the variable, just declare it before the loop.

Can someone explain why the following code:

```
# Bundle/Resources/views/parent
{% set id = 5 %}

# Bundle/Resources/views/child
{% extends 'Bundle::parent.html.twig' %}

{%block one%}
    {% for item in threeitemarray %}
        {% set id = id + 1 %}
        {{id}}
    {%endfor%}
{%endblock%}

{%block two%}
    {% for item in threeitemarray %}
        {% set id = id + 1 %}
        {{id}}
    {%endfor%}
{%endblock%}
```

returns 6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8 instead of 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11?  How should I set it up to return the latter?

Comment: I think it's related to the context that is passed into the blocks, as you have two, they live in different contexts. Have a look at the compiled PHP from your twig template to see what it's actually running.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you explained exactly what you are trying to do, and why you need it to work in that way? Maybe there is an alternative approach to the problem.

Comment: Well, there is and I adopted it already.  I have a set of dom objects that perform a related function, and I want to group them all together so that I can instantize them in jQuery.  I just used a large random number, instead of trying to create a numerical ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your blocks are also defined in parent Twig, I think you can not do that. If it's not the case, try this :

```
# Bundle/Resources/views/parent
{% set id = 5 %}

# Bundle/Resources/views/child
{% extends 'Bundle::parent.html.twig' %}

{% set id = id %}

{%block one%}
    {% for item in threeitemarray %}
        {% set id = id + 1 %}
        {{id}}
    {%endfor%}
{%endblock%}

{%block two%}
    {% for item in threeitemarray %}
        {% set id = id + 1 %}
        {{id}}
    {%endfor%}
{%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
{% set id = 5 %}

{% for item in 0..3 %}
    {% set id = id + 1 %}
    {{id}}
{%endfor%}

{% for item in 0..3 %}
    {% set id = id + 1 %}
    {{id}}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Does not work.  Also, I need the items in the array for other parts of the loop.  This was a simplified example.

Comment: I have tested it and it works fine as yours need.
I think you should update your twig version to latest one

Comment: @AzamAlvi that only works if you don't use blocks, they are the cause of this behaviour as they have their own context.

Comment: @catchamonkey - How could I put a variable into the global context while inside the block context?

Comment: @Morslamina Maybe if you actually registered a variable as a twig global? But that will probably suffer the same fate.

Comment: In twig it is not possible, because the variable scope finish after block end. If you still want to use this approach then make twig extension and use session in that for this purpose.